# how to merge many tables (having same columns) into one table with adding new index column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

1. I have many tables in a sqlite DB file using python with same name and number of columns.
2. and trying to make them into one single table with adding new column in it as indexing purpose.
3. example is as below. Is there anyway to add like 30 tables into one in python?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyjeG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
import pandas as pd


chocolate = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "day": [1, 2, 3],
        "in": [100, 200, 300],
        "out": [1000, 2000, 3000]
    }
)

beverage = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "day": [4, 5, 6],
        "in": [400, 500, 600],
        "out": [4000, 5000, 6000]
    }
)

pizza = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "day": [7, 8, 9],
        "in": [700, 800, 900],
        "out": [7000, 8000, 9000]
    }
)

snacks = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "day": [10, 11, 12],
        "in": [1000, 1100, 1200],
        "out": [10000, 11000, 12000]
    }
)

chips = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "day": [13, 14, 15],
        "in": [1300, 1400, 1500],
        "out": [13000, 14000, 15000]
    }
)


def stringify_variable_name(df: pd.DataFrame) -> str:
    globals_dict = globals()

    return [x for x in globals_dict if globals_dict.get(x) is df][0]


tables = [chocolate, beverage, pizza, snacks, chips]
products = [stringify_variable_name(x) for x in tables]

final_df = pd.concat(tables, keys=products, names=["product", "junk"]).reset_index().drop(columns="junk")

print(final_df)

      product  day    in    out
0   chocolate    1   100   1000
1   chocolate    2   200   2000
2   chocolate    3   300   3000
3    beverage    4   400   4000
4    beverage    5   500   5000
5    beverage    6   600   6000
6       pizza    7   700   7000
7       pizza    8   800   8000
8       pizza    9   900   9000
9      snacks   10  1000  10000
10     snacks   11  1100  11000
11     snacks   12  1200  12000
12      chips   13  1300  13000
13      chips   14  1400  14000
14      chips   15  1500  15000
```

Comment: great solution! Thanks. had lots of time saved! just wondering, what if tables are like 100 then, how can I input all the table objects in the first argument?? (pd.concat([chocolate, beverage...])

Comment: see edit above, you would just set the list of tables.